# Write a MySQL query to find the all the names which contain the word or a part of a word DAVID, sort the result in the order of similarity

Tags: mysql

Example: David, Davi, Dav, Da, D (Names containing the word David, later names containing Davi and so on from employee table with name as a column name)

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only way you can do is:

SELECT Name FROM Employee WHERE NAME LIKE "%DAVID%" OR %DAVI%" OR "%DAV%" OR "%DA%" OR "%D%" ORDER BY Name;